# Force casting to int in python

Tags: python

I have a list of values that I have to use as`int`:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9b4decbf862c> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(Training_Raw)-1):
----> 2     print(int(Training_Raw[row_indeces[i]][-1]))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '5.0'
```

As you can see trying to convert them to `int` through the error message, despite a "valid" values.

Does anybody here has a hint how to solve this ?

Comment: Try `int(float(value))`

Comment: @yeniv u Rock thanks, put it as answer I'll accept it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sting is a `float` value so it first has to be converted to a `float` and then to `int`. This should work:

```
int(float(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because Python expects "integer strings" in this case, e.g. `'5'` instead of `'5.0'`.
One solution is to cast to `float` first and then to `int`:

```
>>> int(float('5.0'))
5
```